# Hive Strange code syntax test.`(submit_date)?+.+

Tags: hive

I have a HQL(Hive Query)  file which has code like

```
  select * ,'(submit_date)?+.+'  from test
```

Table test has several other filed after submit date all of which are returned in the output of this query,  but i couldn't understand how this thing works. ?

does any1 have any idea, i couldn't find any Doc related to this syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented as the [REGEX column specification](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-REGEXColumnSpecification):

> A SELECT statement can take regex-based column specification.
>   We use java regex syntax. Try http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm for testing purposes.
>   The following query select all columns except ds and hr.
>
> ```
> SELECT `(ds|hr)?+.+` FROM sales
> ```